# How to provide two different views in portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im currently working with a IPhone-app that has a "timetable".
in portrait i want it to have a regular table-view with some customization! When i have the IPhone in landscape i want it to change to a more "timetable"-view, with tables and rows.

Is it possible?

Comment: it has to work in both 5.1 and 6.0

Comment: why you want to change the view in landscape view ? Just enable all the orientations in your project .it will automatically auto oriented .please correct me if i misread your question.

Comment: I only want the timetable to be able to rotate in landscape, not the whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Apples documentation [Creating an Alternate Landscape Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14)

Make sure to read the documentation, but here is the code from the example implementation:

```
@implementation PortraitViewController
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {


    [self adjustViewsForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

}

-(void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        //write code for portrait mode
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
       //write code for landscape mode


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes it's possible through the following method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)){
\\ your timetable customisation goes here
     }
}
```

You also need this:

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
       return YES;
    }
```